# Excel, join two tables where join type is parameter

Tags: excel, vba, powerquery

I'm working in Excel and have a bunch of tables in a worksheet that act as inputs.  Ultimately I need to conditionally join these tables to build up a full price table.  This is something I'd be able to do using SQL, but in this case I need to do this for excel. I'm able to use to power query to do basic stuff, but in my case I need a parameter to determine the type of join. Here is an example.

Suppose I have

1. table A with columns: interval1, interval2, and interval3
2. tables B1....Bn, all with the same column names: interval1, interval2, interval3, type, value1, value2, value3
3. table C with columns: table and jointype.

The idea would be, once all the tables have been populated, a macro would run and individually join A to each Bi where the join type is specified table C. Jointype would be a string(factor) with three values:crossJoin, leftJoinBig, leftJoinSmall.  For crossjoin I'd get the cartesian product.  For LeftJoinBig, the join would be a left join on interval1.  For leftJoinSmall the join would be a left join on interval1 and interval2.

Any Ideas?

Answer (score -1):

To implement the three types of JOINs between table A and different table Bs, we need to traverse through table C. This needs a script instead of a formula. A JOIN is a structured computation. But VBA lacks corresponding function to do this directly. The solution code will be rather complicated. Using esProc is much easy.

```
    A   B
1   =file("data.xlsx").xlsopen()    
2   =A1.xlsimport@t(;"C")   
3   =tableA=A1.xlsimport@t(;"A")    
4   for A2  =tableB=A1.xlsimport@t(;A4.table)
5       =case(A4.joinType,    "crossJoin",xjoin(tableA:A;tableB:B),      "leftJoinBig",xjoin@1(tableA:A;tableB:B,A.interval1==interval1),      "leftJoinSmall",xjoin@1(tableA:A;tableB:B,A.interval1==interval1    && A.interval2==interval2))
6       =B5.new(A.interval1,B.interval2,B.interval3,B.type,B.value1,B.value2,B.value3)
7       =file(A4.table+A4.joinType+".xlsx").xlsexport@t(B6)
```

DISCLAIMER: This is about our tool esProc. It’s freemium.

For more explanation, see http://c.raqsoft.com/article/1609981818203